# Display Default Calculator in a fragment

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-fragments, calculator

I'd like to display the system/default calculator using `Fragment`, it's like embedding the calculator in the `ActivityFragment`. The reason for this for multitasking. I have this code below that opens an `Intent` for the calculator but the UI of it occupies the whole screen. I want the system calc to use just half of the screen while I can use the other half for another `Fragment`.

```
public void launchCalculator() {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
        intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(CALCULATOR_PACKAGE_NAME,
               CALCULATOR_CLASS_NAME));
       try {
           this.startActivity(intent);

       } catch (ActivityNotFoundException noSuchActivity) {
           // handle exception where calculator intent filter is not registered
       }

    }
```

Comment: Thats not possible..you are launching the another application Activity. you cant embedd any other app into your fragment..If you want then you need to write your own caluculator..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. There is no "Default calculator" in Android.
2. You can't embed separate app into your app.

Such functionality should be implemented in the system. Some of new phones/tablets from Samsung have similar functionality but it's proprietary implementation and you can't use it.